# Open python scripts in QtCreator

Tags: ros, qtcreator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using Qt creator for cpp catkin projects is straight forward. However, I have a scripts folder in my package that contains python scripts and it is not shown. As Qt creator can edit and run python scripts, I would like to be able to use it for both cpp and python. How can I do that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206050/open-python-scripts-in-qtcreator/) by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on ROS Answers with karma: 3339 on 2015-03-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To open an additional folder from your package add these lines to CMakeLists.txt

```
FILE(GLOB random_name "scripts/*.py")
add_custom_target(random_name2 SOURCES ${random_name})
```

In this example I added my scripts folder containing the python scripts

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2015-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1